# How to post a notification for a custom Core Data property that is dependent on a relationship?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I have a `Client` that has a to-many-relationship to `Invoice`, the property is called `invoices`. Now I wrote a custom read-only property `latestInvoice` which I want to observe in my interface:

```
- (MyInvoice *)latestInvoice
{
  NSArray *invoices = [self valueForKey:@"invoices"];
  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
    sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];

  return invoices.count
    ? [invoices sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]][0]
    : nil;
}
```

I register `Client` as an observer for `invoices`:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
  [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"invoices"];
}

- (void)registerObservers
{
  [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"invoices" options:
    (NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
    context:NULL];
}

- (void)awakeFromInsert
{
  [super awakeFromInsert];

  [self registerObservers];
}

- (void)awakeFromFetch
{
  [super awakeFromFetch];

  [self registerObservers];
}
```

And I manually post change notifications:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
  change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
  if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"invoices"])
  {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"latestInvoice"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"latestInvoice"];
  }
}
```

Is this the right / bug-free / preferred way to do observe Core Data properties that depend on a relationship or do I abuse the framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register `latestInvoice` as a [dependent key](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html) of `invoices`.

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingLatestInvoice {
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"invoices", nil];
}
```

Comment: I should bang my head against the wall. Thanks for the accurate answer. Here’s the corresponding documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFAQ.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001802-DontLinkElementID_13

Comment: Did you verify that this works? There is a section in the docs that states that dependent keys with to-many relationships wont work. But as far as I understood that's only an issue when you're trying to observe properties *of* the elements in your array, and not changes to the array itself (eg. new objects added, objects removed).

Comment: So far it worked for our beta testers without issues. Let’s see what happens after the release.